# “scared a little” vs. “little scared”

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-order

> 1. I’m scared **a little** in this new town.
> 2. I’m **little** scared in this new town.
> 3. I’m **a little** scared in this new town.

Which of these are correct? I think only the 1<sup>st</sup> option is correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos. 1 and 3 reflect a person's feelings of apprehension, whereas no. 2 states, albeit somewhat awkwardly, his fearlessness in his new environment.

No. 2 would look nicely in a verse of the iambic foot:

```
I'm little scared in this new town 
It lifts me up to knuckle down 
In these olds streets where stones are brown 
And people scurry by a-frown
```